# Getting around asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So I have a function like this -

```
    IPGeocoding = (data) ->
    coords = []
    _.each(data, (datum) ->
        $.ajax(
          url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/#{datum}"
          type: 'GET'
          async: false
          success: (result) ->
            lat = result.latitude
            lon = result.longitude
            pair = [lat, lon]
            coords.push(pair)
            console.log coords
        )

    return coords


    )
```

I want coords to only be returned when all of the requests have returned. How do I do that?

Comment: You probably don't want `async: false` unless you hate the people using your site.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore comes bundled with a `_.after` method. `_.after` takes two arguments. The second is the function you want to execute and the first is the number of times you expect it to be called BEFORE you want it executed. It can be used in the following manner to accomplish what you're attempting to do:

```
IPGeocoding = (data, callback) ->
    coords = []
    finish = _.after(data.length, callback)
    _.each(data, (datum) ->
        $.ajax(
            url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/#{datum}"
            type: 'GET'
            async: false
            success: (result) ->
                lat = result.latitude
                lon = result.longitude
                pair = [lat, lon]
                coords.push(pair)
                console.log coords

                finish(coords)
         )
    )
```

Comment: I think your indentation is off (just like it is off in the question).

Comment: I copied it from the question. I never use coffeescript so I honestly don't know what's syntactically correct and what's not.

Comment: The indentation determines the block structure (see [this example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20%3D%20(x)%20-%3E%0Astuff%0A%0Af%20%3D%20(x)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20stuff)) so everything except the first line should be over one level to get it inside the `IPGeocoding` function.

Comment: I think that's what you want for the indentation, `finish` should be called inside the `success` callback (right?) so it needs to be indented to match the rest of the `success` callback, then closing parentheses to balance everything out.

Comment: Oh, I fully understand that it's white space sensitive, @muistooshort, but there were a lot of parenthesis that I didn't understand and rather than alter it, I merely added the components that were required for the solution and left everything else in tact. He'll eventually get the syntax correct, I just wanted to show him the solution he needed.

Comment: why do I need the callback argument?

Comment: That looks right, @muistooshort.

The callback should contain all the code you want to execute after all of the async calls have returned. You can't defer the execution of your return.

Comment: `finish` is a copy of `callback` that will only execute after it's been called `data.length` number of times. After is used to create `finish` from `callback`.