# Getting around asynchronous ajax get

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So I have this function -

```
    IPGeocoding = (data) ->
    coords = []
    finish = _.after(data.length, (coords) ->
      console.log coords
      return coords
    )
    _.each(data, (datum) ->
        $.ajax(
          url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/#{datum}"
          type: 'GET'
          success: (result) ->
            lat = result.latitude
            lon = result.longitude
            pair = [lat, lon]
            coords.push(pair)
            finish(coords)
        )
    )
```

It's being called like this

```
if @model.get('data')?
  if @model.get('func')?
    @points = @model.get('func')(@model.get('data'))
```

however, @points is undefined. I want @points to be what coords is when console.log coords is run(which is an array of some length). I'm using _.after because I want to build coords up from the results of multipl async calls.

How do I get the coordinates to be in coords?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  @points is not your function.  So, why does it matter whether or not it is defined?

Comment: I dont see how the first half of your code is related to your second half? Also, I dont know which framework you are using, however `get` will have to support an async pattern if you are trying to retrieve the `coords`.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out the `callback` parameter to `IPGeocoding` from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305860/479863). You're supposed to be doing this:

```
IPGeocoding = (data, callback) ->
  finish = _.after(data.length, callback)
  #...
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
IPGeocoding(data, (coords) ->
  # Do whatever needs to be done with `coords`
  # in here.
)
```

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#after):

> **after** `_.after(count, function)`
>
> Creates a version of the function that will only be run after first being called **count** times. Useful for grouping asynchronous responses, where you want to be sure that all the async calls have finished, before proceeding.

So the `finish` call won't do anything until all the `$.ajax` calls have successfully returned and then `callback` will be called with the final `coords`.

Also note that there's no guarantee that the order of `coords` will match the order of `data`. If you need to maintain the order then you'll need to build an object in `coords` instead of an array and then re-order things at the end. Assuming that `datum` is a simple scalar you could do something like this:

```
coords = { }
finish = _.after(data.length, (coords) ->
  in_order = (coords[datum] for datum in data)
  callback(in_order)
)
```

and then in the `success` handler you'd say `coords[datum] = pair` instead of `coords.push(pair)`.